# Angular : Issue with dynamic form

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic

I have a subform that I would like to be dynamic, i.e. One select field value changes the content of the other select field and set default value if it exists.

The dependent select options are well changed, but patching default values is not working...

Here is the .ts:

```
    export interface GsmattFormValues {
    id: number,
    mattype: number,
    material: number,
}
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-gsmatt',
  templateUrl: './gsmatt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gsmatt.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => GsmattComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => GsmattComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class GsmattComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() inMandatoryObjects: any;
  @Input() inErrors: any[];

  mattypes: Mattype[];
  materials: Material[];

  allowMaterials: boolean = false;

  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  gsmattForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    ) { 
    }

  get f() { return this.gsmattForm.controls; }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// OnInit & onDestroy
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.mattypes=this.inMandatoryObjects['mattypes'];
        this.materials=this.inMandatoryObjects['materials'];
        this.initForm();
        this.gsmattForm.valueChanges.takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(value => {
            this.onChange(value);
            this.onTouched();
        });
        
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Control Value Accessor
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  get value(): GsmattFormValues {
    return this.gsmattForm.value;
  }

  set value(value: GsmattFormValues) {
    //if( value !== undefined && this.value !== value){ 
    if( value !== undefined ){      
        this.configureMatRCP(this.mattypes.find(item => item.id==value.mattype));
        this.gsmattForm.patchValue(value);
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
    }
  }

  onChange: any = () => {}

  onTouched: any = () => {
  }

  // this method sets the value programmatically
  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    if (value === null) {
      this.gsmattForm.reset();
    }

  }

// upon UI element value changes, this method gets triggered
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

// upon touching the element, this method gets triggered
  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // communicate the inner form validation to the parent form
  validate(_: FormControl) {
    return this.gsmattForm.valid ? null : { profile: { valid: false } };
  }

  get errors() {
    return this.gsmattForm.errors ? null : this.gsmattForm.errors;
  }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///// Miscellaneous Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  initForm() {
    this.gsmattForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: '',
        mattype: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, SelectedValue]),
        material: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// Event Functions
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  onMattypeChange(event) {
    var MATP;
    if (event) {MATP=this.mattypes.find(item => item.id==event);}
    console.log("UPDATING");
    this.configureMatRCP(MATP);
    this.setDfltValues(MATP);
  }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// Dynamic Form Functions
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  configureMatRCP(mattype?: Mattype) {
    console.log("FOrm "+JSON.stringify(this.gsmattForm.value));
    if (mattype) {
        this.materials=this.inMandatoryObjects['materials'].filter(item => item.mattype.id==mattype.id);
        if (this.materials.length>0) {
            this.gsmattForm.get("material").enable();
            this.allowMaterials=true;
        }
        else {
            this.gsmattForm.get("material").disable();
            this.allowMaterials=false;          
        }
    }
    else {
        this.allowMaterials=false;
        this.gsmattForm.get("material").disable();
    }

  }

  setDfltValues(mattype?: Mattype) {
    if (mattype) {
        var materialsTmp=this.inMandatoryObjects['materials'].filter(item => item.mattype.id==mattype.id);
        if (materialsTmp.length>0) {
            var dfltMaterial = materialsTmp.find(item => item.isdefault==true);
            console.log("DFLMATERIAL "+JSON.stringify(dfltMaterial));
            if (dfltMaterial) {console.log("BOOM "+dfltMaterial.id); 
                this.gsmattForm.patchValue({material: dfltMaterial.id});
            }
            else {this.gsmattForm.patchValue({material: ''});}
        }
        else {
            this.gsmattForm.patchValue({material: ''});     
        }
    }
    else {
        this.gsmattForm.patchValue({material: ''});
    }

  }

}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-body>    
        <div [formGroup]="gsmattForm">
                  
          <input type="hidden" nbInput fullWidth id="id" formControlName="id"/>  
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mattype" class="label">{{ 'MATTYPE' | translate }}</label>
                <nb-select id="mattype" formControlName="mattype" fullWidth status="basic"
                placeholder="{{ 'MATTYPE' | translate }}" (selectedChange)="onMattypeChange($event)">
                  <nb-option *ngFor="let option of mattypes" [value]="option.id">
                    {{ option.label | translate }}
                  </nb-option>
                </nb-select>
                <div *ngIf="f.mattype.touched && f.mattype.errors" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                    <div *ngIf="f.mattype.errors['required']">{{ 'FIELD_REQUIRED' | translate: {field: 'MATTYPE' | translate} }}</div>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="allowMaterials"> 
              <div class="form-group" >
                <label for="material" class="label">{{ 'MATERIAL' | translate }}</label>
                <nb-select id="material" formControlName="material" fullWidth status="{{ (f.material.errors && f.material.touched) ? 'danger': (!f.material.errors && f.material.touched) ? 'success' : 'basic' }}"
                    placeholder="{{ 'MATERIAL' | translate }}">
                    <nb-option *ngFor="let option of materials" [value]="option.id">
                        {{ option.label | translate }}
                    </nb-option>
                </nb-select>
                <div *ngIf="f.material.touched && f.material.errors" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                    <div *ngIf="f.material.errors['required']">{{ 'FIELD_REQUIRED' | translate: {field: 'MATERIAL' | translate} }}</div>
                </div>
             </div>     
            </div>  
            </div>
        </div>      
      </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT 1 : after surching a lot, it appears to be a conflict between select option filtering and patching Value. I then try to use callback to be sure to wait select options update before setting the value.

```
  configureMatRCP(setDfltValue: boolean, callback, mattype?: Mattype) {
    console.log("FOrm "+JSON.stringify(this.gsmattForm.value));
    if (mattype) {
        this.materials=this.inMandatoryObjects['materials'].filter(item => item.mattype.id==mattype.id);
        if (this.materials.length>0) {
            this.gsmattForm.get("material").enable();
            this.allowMaterials=true;
        }
        else {
            this.gsmattForm.get("material").disable();
            this.allowMaterials=false;          
        }

    }
    else {
        this.allowMaterials=false;
        this.gsmattForm.get("material").disable();
    }
    if(setDfltValue) {
        callback(mattype); 
    }

  }
```

and

```
  onMattypeChange(event) {
    var MATP;
    if (event) {MATP=this.mattypes.find(item => item.id==event);}
    console.log("UPDATING");
    this.configureMatRCP(true, this.setDfltValues(MATP), MATP);
    //this.setDfltValues(MATP);
  }
```

but I get the error callback is not a function...
what did I miss?

Comment: can you make a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: here it is, but get an error on formGroup : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k57ro1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgsmatt.component.html

Comment: here it is  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k57ro1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgsmatt.component.html
It is a simplified version of the project and it works on stackblitz...

Comment: When I console.log form.value after the value patch, it object contains my new value but it is as if the main form was not updated with the set value

Comment: Need some help please ! on Stackblitz it works, but not on ma dev system. The first select changes the second default values only the first time

Comment: In fact changing the select options is conflicting with the set value. How can I properly wait the options of the select are well changed before paching my value?

Comment: Hi , is it possible to write down your phone to contact .thx

Comment: skype? my pseudo alexglvr

Comment: I'm at work  ,8 hours later call you ...